# PHP Copying a set of files to a differnt directory

Tags: php

I am trying to copy a bunch of xlsx files to a different directory, I want to know what is that I am doing wrong

```html
  // Move all xlsx files
   $src = './';
  // echo "<pre>";print_r($src);die;
   $dst = 'files/';
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($dst);die;
   $files = glob("*.xlsx");
   //echo "<pre>"; print_r($files);die;
   foreach($files as $file){
       $file_to_go = ($dst,$file);
      echo  "<pre>";print_r($file_to_go);die;
       copy($file, $file_to_go);
   }
```

Comment: What's in your php error log?

Comment: No error displayed , I want to know if the the syntax used is correct-- this one mainly -----$file_to_go = ($dst,$file);

Comment: There's a random closing bracket at the end of your script but I assume that's a copy/paste error. `php -l <filename>` will tell you if the file parses.

Comment: No error displayed, but what about the error log? Add `error_reporting E_ALL; ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the file.

Comment: `$file_to_go = ($dst,$file);` makes no sense. It should probably be `.` instead of `,`

Comment: when I echo the $files variable it displays the value , but does not copy to the destination folder, so I am assuming it is a syntax error

Comment: error_reporting E_ALL; ini_set('display_errors', 1); is already set - or just guide to somelink which provides solutions to my need

Comment: Before your copy: `echo "file: ".$file. " file_to_go: ".$file_to_go;` are they what you expect?

Comment: mine is a simple need , I need to copy files from a directory with .xlsx extension and copy to a folder

Comment: Are you even reading the comments?

Comment: let me try your logic, looks like it will resolve my need